# What is the difference between packaged_task and async

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stdasync, packaged-task

While working with the threaded model of C++11, I noticed that

```
std::packaged_task<int(int,int)> task([](int a, int b) { return a + b; });
auto f = task.get_future();
task(2,3);
std::cout << f.get() << '\n';
```

and

```
auto f = std::async(std::launch::async, 
    [](int a, int b) { return a + b; }, 2, 3);
std::cout << f.get() << '\n';
```

seem to do exactly the same thing. I understand that there could be a major difference if I ran `std::async` with `std::launch::deferred`, but is there one in this case?

What is the difference between these two approaches, and more importantly, in what use cases should I use one over the other?

Answer (score 220, accepted):

Actually the example you just gave shows the differences if you use a rather long function, such as

```
//! sleeps for one second and returns 1
auto sleep = [](){
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    return 1;
};
```

### Packaged task

A `packaged_task` won't start on its own, you have to invoke it:

```
std::packaged_task<int()> task(sleep);

auto f = task.get_future();
task(); // invoke the function

// You have to wait until task returns. Since task calls sleep
// you will have to wait at least 1 second.
std::cout << "You can see this after 1 second\n";

// However, f.get() will be available, since task has already finished.
std::cout << f.get() << std::endl;
```

### `std::async`

On the other hand, `std::async` with `launch::async` will try to run the task in a different thread:

```
auto f = std::async(std::launch::async, sleep);
std::cout << "You can see this immediately!\n";

// However, the value of the future will be available after sleep has finished
// so f.get() can block up to 1 second.
std::cout << f.get() << "This will be shown after a second!\n";
```

#### Drawback

But before you try to use `async` for everything, keep in mind that the returned future has a special shared state, which demands that `future::~future` blocks:

```
std::async(do_work1); // ~future blocks
std::async(do_work2); // ~future blocks

/* output: (assuming that do_work* log their progress)
    do_work1() started;
    do_work1() stopped;
    do_work2() started;
    do_work2() stopped;
*/
```

So if you want real asynchronous you need to keep the returned `future`, or if you don't care for the result if the circumstances change:

```
{
    auto pizza = std::async(get_pizza);
    /* ... */
    if(need_to_go)
        return;          // ~future will block
    else
       eat(pizza.get());
}
```

For more information on this, see Herb Sutter's article [`async` and `~future`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3451.pdf), which describes the problem, and Scott Meyer's [`std::futures` from `std::async` aren't special](http://scottmeyers.blogspot.de/2013/03/stdfutures-from-stdasync-arent-special.html), which describes the insights. Also do note that this behavior [was specified in C++14 and up](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/%7Efuture), but also commonly implemented in C++11.

### Further differences

By using `std::async` you cannot run your task on a specific thread anymore, where `std::packaged_task` can be moved to other threads.

```
std::packaged_task<int(int,int)> task(...);
auto f = task.get_future();
std::thread myThread(std::move(task),2,3);

std::cout << f.get() << "\n";
```

Also, a `packaged_task` needs to be invoked before you call `f.get()`, otherwise you program will freeze as the future will never become ready:

```
std::packaged_task<int(int,int)> task(...);
auto f = task.get_future();
std::cout << f.get() << "\n"; // oops!
task(2,3);
```

### TL;DR

Use `std::async` if you want some things done and don't really care when they're done, and `std::packaged_task` if you want to wrap up things in order to move them to other threads or call them later. Or, to quote [Christian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18143661/what-is-the-difference-between-packaged-task-and-async/18143844#comment26578667_18143844):

> In the end a `std::packaged_task` is just a lower level feature for implementing `std::async` (which is why it can do more than `std::async` if used together with other lower level stuff, like `std::thread`). Simply spoken a `std::packaged_task` is a `std::function` linked to a `std::future` and `std::async` wraps and calls a `std::packaged_task` (possibly in a different thread).

Comment: You should add that the future returned by async blocks on destruction (as if you called get) whereas the one returned from packaged_task does not.

Comment: In the end a `std::packaged_task` is just a lower level feature for implementing `std::async` (which is why it can do more than `std::async` if used together with other lower level stuff, like `std::thread`). *Simply* spoken a `std::packaged_task` is a `std::function` linked to a `std::future` and `std::async` wraps and calls a `std::packaged_task` (possibly in a different thread).

Comment: I am doing some experiments on the ~future() block. I could not replicate the blocking effect on the future object destruction. Everything worked asynchronously. I am using VS 2013 and when i launch the async, I used std::launch::async. Does VC++ somehow "fixed" this issue?

Comment: @FrankLiu: Well, N3451 is a an accepted proposal, which (as far as I know) went into C++14. Given that Herb works at Microsoft, I wouldn't be surprised if that feature is implemented in VS2013. A compiler that strictly follows the C++11 rules would still show this behaviour.

Comment: "in C++14 this destructor will not block in the calling thread" - I believe this is not what C++17 standard says. See 33.6.5.5.3 (referenced from 33.6.7.9, describing effects of `~future()`): "these actions will not block for the shared state to become ready, except that it may block if all of the following are true: the shared state was created by a call to **std::async**, the shared state is not yet ready, and this was the last reference to the shared state"

Comment: @Mikhail This answer precedes both C++14 and C++17, so I didn't have the standards but only proposals at hand. I'll remove the paragraph.

Comment: I'd also add that `std::packaged_task` is the perfect fit to implement a thread pool queue

Answer (score 11):

## TL;DR

`std::packaged_task` allows us to get the `std::future` "bounded" to some *callable*, and then control when and where this callable will be executed without the need of that future object.

`std::async` enables the first, but not the second. Namely, it allows us to get the future for some callable, but then, we have no control of its execution without that future object.

## Practical example

Here is a practical example of a problem that can be solved with `std::packaged_task` but not with `std::async`.

Consider you want to implement a *thread pool*. It consists of a fixed number of *worker threads* and a *shared queue*. But shared queue of what? `std::packaged_task` is quite suitable here.

```
template <typename T>
class ThreadPool {
public:
  using task_type = std::packaged_task<T()>;

  std::future<T> enqueue(task_type task) {
      // could be passed by reference as well...
      // ...or implemented with perfect forwarding
    std::future<T> res = task.get_future();
    { std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
      tasks_.push(std::move(task));
    }
    cv_.notify_one();
    return res;
  }

  void worker() { 
    while (true) {  // supposed to be run forever for simplicity
      task_type task;
      { std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
        cv_.wait(lock, [this]{ return !this->tasks_.empty(); });
        task = std::move(tasks_.top());
        tasks_.pop();
      }
      task();
    }
  }
  ... // constructors, destructor,...
private:
  std::vector<std::thread> workers_;
  std::queue<task_type> tasks_;
  std::mutex mutex_;
  std::condition_variable cv_;
};
```

Such functionality cannot be implemented with `std::async`. We need to return an `std::future` from `enqueue()`. If we called `std::async` there (even with *deferred* policy) and return `std::future`, then we would have no option how to execute the callable in `worker()`. Note that you cannot create multiple futures for the same shared state (futures are non-copyable).

Comment: I believe that the statement that such functionality is impossible to implement with `std::async` is not entirely correct. We can use the `std::launch::deferred` policy which effectively makes `std::async` behave very similar to `std::packaged_task` if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @niosus No, that's not true. With the deferred policy, you still need the future object to (then synchronously) execute the task. A packaged task can be executed independently of the corresponding future.

Comment: I agree on that, but one _can_ implement such a thread pool as you did above by having a queue of futures and creating them from `std::function` objects through the `std::async` tasks having the `std::launch::deferred` policy. This way we can still perform the actual work form the worker thread. We would only have to share the future with the outside then. I think using `std::packaged_task` is better for this but just wanted to point out that it _is_ possible to implement a similar thing with the `std::async`.

Comment: @niosus Allright, yes, this would be possible. `std::shared_future` might be a suitable tool.

Answer (score 1):

### Packaged Task vs async

***p>*** Packaged task holds a task `[function or function object]` and future/promise pair. When the task executes a return statement, it causes `set_value(..)` on the `packaged_task`'s promise.

***a>*** Given Future, promise and package task we can create simple tasks without worrying too much about threads [thread is just something we give to run a task].

However we need to consider how many threads to use or whether a task is best run on the current thread or on another etc.Such descisions can be handled by a thread launcher called `async()`, that decides whether to create a new a thread or recycle an old one or simply run the task on the current thread. It returns a future .

Answer (score 0):

> "The class template std::packaged_task wraps any callable target
>   (function, lambda expression, bind expression, or another function
>   object) so that it can be invoked asynchronously. Its return value or
>   exception thrown is stored in a shared state which can be accessed
>   through std::future objects."
>
> "The template function async runs the function f asynchronously
>   (potentially in a separate thread) and returns a std::future that will
>   eventually hold the result of that function call."