# Why is std::async slow compared to simple detached threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, asynchronous, stdasync

I've been told several times, that I should use `std::async` for fire & forget type of tasks with the `std::launch::async` parameter (so it does it's magic on a new thread of execution preferably).

Encouraged by these statements, I wanted to see how `std::async` is compared to:

- sequential execution
- a simple detached `std::thread`
- my simple async "implementation"

My naive async implementation looks like this:

```
template <typename F, typename... Args>
auto myAsync(F&& f, Args&&... args) -> std::future<decltype(f(args...))>
{
    std::packaged_task<decltype(f(args...))()> task(std::bind(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...));
    auto future = task.get_future();

    std::thread thread(std::move(task));
    thread.detach();

    return future;
}
```

Nothing fancy here, packs the functor `f` into an `std::packaged task` along with its arguments, launches it on a new `std::thread` which is detached, and returns with the `std::future` from the task.

And now the code measuring execution time with `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`:

```
int main(void)
{
    constexpr unsigned short TIMES = 1000;

    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < TIMES; ++i)
    {
        someTask();
    }
    auto dur = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start;

    auto tstart = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < TIMES; ++i)
    {
        std::thread t(someTask);
        t.detach();
    }
    auto tdur = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - tstart;

    std::future<void> f;
    auto astart = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < TIMES; ++i)
    {
        f = std::async(std::launch::async, someTask);
    }
    auto adur = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - astart;

    auto mastart = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < TIMES; ++i)
    {
        f = myAsync(someTask);
    }
    auto madur = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - mastart;

    std::cout << "Simple: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(dur).count() <<
    std::endl << "Threaded: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(tdur).count() <<
    std::endl << "std::sync: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(adur).count() <<
    std::endl << "My async: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(madur).count() << std::endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Where `someTask()` is a simple method, where I wait a little, simulating some work done:

```
void someTask()
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
}
```

Finally, my results:

- Sequential: 1263615
- Threaded: 47111
- std::sync: 821441
- My async: 30784

Could anyone **explain these results**? It seems like `std::aysnc` is much **slower than my naive implementation**, or just plain and simple **detached** `std::thread`s. **Why** is that? After these results is there any reason to use `std::async`?

(Note that I did this benchmark with clang++ and g++ too, and the results were very similar)

**UPDATE:**

After reading Dave S's answer I updated my little benchmark as follows:

```
std::future<void> f[TIMES];
auto astart = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
for (int i = 0; i < TIMES; ++i)
{
    f[i] = std::async(std::launch::async, someTask);
}
auto adur = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - astart;
```

So the `std::future`s are now not destroyed - and thus joined - every run. After this change in the code, `std::async` produces similar results to my implementation & detached `std::thread`s.

Comment: I'm sure this is not the issue, but I just have to ask for completeness of information. Are you measuring a debug (unoptimized) or release (optimized) build? I assume an optimized build as otherwise any measurements would be pointless, but I have to ask.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Totally valid question, but I am measuring with -O2.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One key difference is that the future returned by async joins the thread when the future is destroyed, or in your case, replaced with a new value.

This means it has to execute `someTask()` and join the thread, both of which take time.  None of your other tests are doing that, where they simply spawn them independently.

Comment: "*the future returned by async joins the thread when the future is destroyed*" AKA: the primary reason to never, *ever* use `std::async`.

Comment: @KerrekSB: If you wanted that, you should call `future::wait` explicitly, just like you would do for every other `future`. The problem is that the `future` returned by `async` has different behavior from *every other `future` object*. It's the inconsistency that's the problem, not the behavior. The inconsistent, and non-user-reproducible, behavior of this makes it very easy to accidentally do the wrong thing, as was done here.

Comment: Thank you, this solved the mystery. But still, what is the reason behind this behaviour? Could you point me some article on this matter, or something like that?

Comment: @krispetkrispet part of this is answered [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18143661/what-is-the-difference-between-packaged-task-and-async/18143844#18143844) (disclaimer: I wrote that one). [Scott Meyer's also wrote an article](http://scottmeyers.blogspot.de/2013/03/stdfutures-from-stdasync-arent-special.html).. Either way, that part of future was heavily discussed back in 2012/2013, I'm not sure what the final verdict was, though.

Answer (score 8):

`sts::async` returns a special `std::future`.  This future has a `~future` that does a `.wait()`.

So your examples are fundamentally different.  The slow ones actually do the tasks during your timing.  The fast ones just queue up the tasks, and forget how to ever know the task is done.  As the behaviour of programs that let threads last past the end of main is unpredictable, one should avoid it.

The right way to compare the tasks is to store the resulting `future` when genersting, and before the timer ends either `.wait()`/`.join()` them all, or avoid destroying the objects until after the timer expires.  This last case, however, makes the sewuential version look worse than it is.

You do need to join/wait before starting the next test, as otherwise you are stealing resources from their timing.

Note that moved futures remove the wait from the source.